# With C3.js, how can I maintain bar width ratio when zooming in?

Tags: c3.js

I have a c3.js bar graph with a subgraph and zooming enabled. I would like for the graph to show more x-tick labels and make the bars a little wider when the user selects a smaller area.

Here's what my graph looks like zoomed out (left) and zoomed in (right):

[image: Zoomed Out][image: Zoomed In]

[Here's a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/2g9sLxhp/)

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#chart',
    data: {
      x: 'x',
      columns: [
        ['x', '2015-01-01', '2015-02-01', '2015-03-01', '2015-04-01', '2015-05-01', '2015-06-01', '2015-07-01', '2015-08-01', '2015-09-01', '2015-10-01', '2015-11-01', '2015-12-01', '2016-01-01', '2016-02-01', '2016-03-01', '2016-04-01', '2016-05-01', '2016-06-01', '2016-07-01', '2016-08-01'],
        ['y', 100, 200, 300, 200, 100, 450, 800, 900, 12, 70, 500, 450, 20, 100, 200, 300, 200, 100, 450, 800, 900, 12, 70, 500, 450, 20]
      ],
      type: 'bar',
      color: function(color, d) {
        var color = d3.rgb("#E47911");
        if (d.index % 2 == 0) {
          color = color.darker(1.2);
        }
        return color;
      }
    },
    bar: {
      width: { ratio: 1.0 }
    },
    axis: {
      x: {
        type: 'timeseries',
        tick: {
          format: "%b",
          fit: true
        }
      },
    },
    subchart: {
      show: true
    }, 
    zoom: {
      enabled: true
    }
});
```

I'd like it to look more like this when zoomed in:

[image: What I want].

Is there a way to make this happen using C3?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the subchart functionality on C3, but my guess would be that it just modifies the spacing/margin between the bars as you zoom/unzoom in the subchart, hiding any overflow. What you're wanting is to adjust the bar size, rather than the spacing, and to alter the tick culling too.  Looking at the C3 reference, I don't see that as an option. So I'd imagine you either have to modify the C3 code, or manipulate the chart yourself using D3 after C3 has rendered the subchart zoom. That's my best guess.

Answer (score 0):

copy the code to your fiddle js panel.  **type: 'categories'** changes the bar scales.

```
var chart = c3.generate({
bindto: '#chart',
data: {
  x: 'x',
  columns: [
    ['x', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
    ['y', 100, 200, 300, 200, 100, 450, 800, 900, 12, 70, 500, 450, 20, 100, 200, 300, 200, 100, 450, 800, 900, 12, 70, 500, 450, 20]
  ],
  type: 'bar',
  color: function(color, d) {
    var color = d3.rgb("#E47911");
    if (d.index % 2 == 0) {
      color = color.darker(1.2);
    }
    return color;
  }
},
bar: {
  width: { ratio: 0.8 }
},
axis: {
  x: {
    type: 'categories',
    tick: {
      format: "%b",
      fit: true
    }
  },
},
subchart: {
  show: true
}, 
zoom: {
  enabled: true
}
});
```